# Matrix inversion in python: bottom diagonal always wrong

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, inversion

I am writing a program that inverts an n*n dimensional square matrix without explicit dependence on the numpy.linalg.inv function, however the bottom left triangular matrix is always incorrect, whereas the rest of the matrix elements are always correct. I have combed through the code multiple times but I can't figure out why the bottom left triangular matrix is the only part that is incorrect.

I have re-written the program multiple times and attempted to isolate each section to see if it does what is intended, however I can't determine what is wrong.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import delete as npd

def Main():
    mat = np.array(([1,2,5],
                    [4,1,1],
                    [1,2,3]))
    print("Original Matrix")
    print(mat)
    print("Inverted Matrix")
    print(Invert(mat))
    print("Correct Matrix")
    print(np.linalg.inv(mat))

def Invert(mat):
    det = Determinant(mat)
    if(len(mat) == 2):
        smolMat = mat  # Matrix to hold all the smaller values
        smolMat[0][0], smolMat[1][1] = mat[1][1]/det, mat[0][0]/det
        smolMat[1][0], smolMat[0][1] = -mat[1][0]/det, -mat[0][1]/det
        return smolMat
    coMat = np.zeros((len(mat), len(mat)))
    for i in range(0, len(mat)):
        for j in range(0, len(mat)):
            minMat = Minor(mat, i, j)
            coMat[i][j] = (((-1)**(i+j)) * Determinant(minMat))
    return TransAndCo(coMat, det)

def Determinant(mat):
    if(len(mat) == 2):
        return ((mat[0][0] * mat[1][1]) - (mat[0][1] * mat[1][0]))
    det = 0
    for i in range(0, len(mat)):
        det += ((-1) ** i) * mat[0][i] * Determinant(Minor(mat, 0, i))
    return det

def Minor(mat, i, j):
    return npd(npd(mat,i,0),j,1)

def TransAndCo(mat, det):
    tempMat = mat
    for i in range(0, len(mat)):
        for j in range(0, len(mat)):
            tempMat[i][j] = mat[j][i]/det
    return tempMat

Main()
```

Expected output in this case is

```
[[ 0.07142857  0.28571429 -0.21428571]
 [ 0.02040816 -0.14285714  1.35714286]
 [-0.01530612  0.09693878 -0.5       ]]
```

But the correctly inverted matrix is:

```
[[ 0.07142857  0.28571429 -0.21428571]
 [-0.78571429 -0.14285714  1.35714286]
 [ 0.5        -0.         -0.5       ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realised the main issue with the code. In the transposition function I call tempmat = mat which raises errors as it should be tempmat = np.array(mat)